# How to alternate 5 values of 0 and and 5 values of 1 using pthread in C?

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a small assignment using C language that populates an integer array of size 30 with alternating 5 values of 0 (written by one thread) and 5 values of 1 (written by a second thread).

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

 int count = 0;
 int oktogo = 1; //0 is false, 1 is true. For thread2 this is reversed.

  pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
  pthread_cond_t condition = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

  void *start_thread_one()
  {
    int i;
     for (i=1;i<30;i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while (oktogo == 0)
           pthread_cond_wait(&condition, &mutex);
        count=0;
        printf("thread one: %d\n", count);
        oktogo = 0;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        pthread_cond_signal(&condition);
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
    }

 void *start_thread_two()
 {
   int i;
    for(i=1;i<30;i++) {
       pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
       while (oktogo == 1)
           pthread_cond_wait(&condition, &mutex);
       count =1;
       printf("thread two: %d\n", count);
       oktogo = 1;
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
       pthread_cond_signal(&condition);
   }
   pthread_exit(0);
 }

 int main ()
 {
  int count = 0;
  pthread_t p1,p2;

  pthread_create(&p1,NULL,(void *)start_thread_one,NULL);
  pthread_create(&p2,NULL,(void *)start_thread_two,NULL);

   pthread_join(p1,NULL);
   pthread_join(p2,NULL);

   return(0);
}
```

The output just showed the value of thread one which is 0 then thread two which is 1. How can I print out 5 values of 0 then 5 values of 1 alternately instead of one by one?

The screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The question says "populate an array" but you have not done that. If you populate a shared array then you can print it afterwards.

Comment: How can I do that? any suggestion? I a new in C so I do not know how to do that. My instructor did not mention about that too :(

Comment: Does this mean that the final array should be: `0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,...`? And, can each thread do 5 values on a single iteration?

Comment: yes. it is. How can I do that @CraigEstey

Comment: as mentioned, you're not populating an array, and to me it appears you're missing the point of the assignment. I see no need for a mutex or conditional variable (unless these are part of the assignment??) I would simply have thread 1 write 0s to locations 0-4, 10-14, etc and thread 2 write 1s to locations 5-9, 15-19, etc. Since the threads are touching different memory, no need to protect the array with a mutex. Plus that way you get the benefit of work being done in parallel, which is the whole point of threads anyway. Then print out the array in `main` after both have `joined`

Comment: I have fixed it. Thanks for you all :D

Answer (score 1):

Your thread sync logic appears to be fine.

The only issue was that you weren't actually storing into an array when you had the chance [And having the main thread] print it out after joining the threads.

Also, you don't really need *two* separate thread functions. You can use a single one that takes an argument/value of either 0 or 1. That is, the arg specifies the starting offset into the array for the thread and the value to store and the needed value for `oktogo`.

Anyway, here's a working version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int count = 0;
int oktogo = 0;                         // 0 is false, 1 is true. For thread2 this is reversed.

#define CHUNK       5
int array[5000];

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t condition = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *
start_thread(void *ptr)
{
    long self = (long) ptr;
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        while (oktogo != self)
            pthread_cond_wait(&condition, &mutex);

        printf("thread %ld: %d\n",self,count);
        for (int idx = 0;  idx < CHUNK;  ++idx, ++count)
            array[count] = self;

        oktogo = ! self;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        pthread_cond_signal(&condition);
    }

    pthread_exit(0);
}

int
main()
{
    int count = 0;
    pthread_t p1,
     p2;

    for (int idx = 0;  idx < sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);  ++idx)
        array[idx] = -1;

    pthread_create(&p1, NULL, (void *) start_thread, (void *) 0);
    pthread_create(&p2, NULL, (void *) start_thread, (void *) 1);

    pthread_join(p1, NULL);
    pthread_join(p2, NULL);

    for (int idx = 0;  idx < sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);  ++idx) {
        if (array[idx] >= 0)
            printf("%d: %d\n",idx,array[idx]);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot. I appreciated your help :D

Answer (score 0):

When thinking about parallel programming there are two designs that you can think
 1. Each thread does something different
 2. Each thread does something very similar, but over specific indices

I would specify the range that you want thread 0 and thread 1 etc to cover and input their values there.